# How to prove that $M_2(\mathbb{H})$ is simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $M_2(\mathbb{H})$ is simple.

What I have done so far:
To prove that a $\mathbb{R}$-algebra is simple it is required to prove that its only two-sided ideals are $\left \{0\right \}$ and $M_2(\mathbb{H})$. So, I take a two-sided ideal $M\neq \left \{0\right \}$ of $M_2(\mathbb{H})$ and try to prove that it must then be equal to $M_2(\mathbb{H})$. Since $M\neq \left\{0\right \}$ there must be an $A \neq 0$ in $M$. We have that $A$ is either invertible or not. If $A$ is invertible then the result is clear. My problem is the case where $A$ is not invertible.

I've thought about it and maybe by computing $\det(A)$ which must be equal to $0$ in this case we'll arrive to a contradiction? Or maybe a multiplication of $A$ with a matrix in $M_2(\mathbb{H})$ allows us to find an invertible element in $M$?

I know that this can be proven with the Brauer Group and/or the Wedderburn Theorem, but I would like use the definition of a simple algebra to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if $A$ is a simple algebra, then so is $M_n(A)$. You can show this in two parts:

- Show any basis matrix $e_{ij}$ (with $ij$-entry $1$ and all other entries $0$) generates all of $M_n(A)$ as a two-sided ideal. (Hint: multiply it by permutation matrices on the left and right.)
- Show that if $X$ is nonzero, then the two-sided ideal it generates contains some $e_{ij}$. (Hint: multiply it by diagonal projection matrices $e_{ii}$ on the left and the right.)